# Subsetting timeseries data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, subset, xts

```
ggplot(Price.data['2000-01/2015-12'],aes(x=Demand,y=Price))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method=lm)

indexClass(Price.data)
[1] "Date"
```

How to plot only March, April and June data from year 2010-2014?

```
 head(Price.data)
        Dry_Gas_Y Power_Gas_Y Price_Gas_Y
1990-01-01  52.16720    5.469179        2.39
1990-02-01  51.45287    5.470755        1.90
1990-03-01  49.29829    6.908609        1.55
1990-04-01  48.29243    7.721371        1.49
1990-05-01  47.25959    9.154057        1.47
1990-06-01  47.48744   11.525595        1.47
```

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example? or a sample of your dataset ? In particular, we need to the format of your `date` column

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

Price.data %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(format(Date, "%Y")),
         month = as.numeric(format(Date, "%m"))) %>%
  filter(year > 2009 & year < 2015, month == 3 | month == 4 | month ==6) %>%     
ggplot(aes(Demand,Price))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table`, which is likely to be the fastest solution

```
library(data.table)   


# convert your dataset into a data.table
  setDT(df)

# If necessary, get date column into date format
#  df[ , Date := as.Date(df$Date, "%m-%d-%y") ] 

# Create separate columns for year and month
  df[, year := year(Date)][, month := month(Date)]

# filter dataset
  df <- df[ month %in% c(3,4,6) & year %in% c(2009:2014), ]
  #  subset(df, month %in% c(3,4,6) & year %in% c(2009:2014) ) # you could also use a simple subset, but this is likely to be slower
```

Plot

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Demand, y=Price)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example I didn't see the dates having a column name and it looks like the dates are the row names. For this reason, this example creates a 'Date' column, then 'Month' & 'Year' columns for you to then filter the dates.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr

plot_months <- Price.data%>%
               mutate(Date = row.names(.),
                      Month = month(Date),
                      Year = year(Date))%>%
               filter(Month %in% c(3,4,6),
                      Year %in% c(2009:2014))

ggplot(plot_months, aes(x=Demand,y=Price))+
       geom_point()+
       geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Price.data` is an xts object, you can use the `.indexmon` function to extract the months you want to plot. Then use range-based subsetting to extracting the range of years you want.

Note that `.indexmon` returns the months starting with January = 0, like the `$mon` element of `POSIXlt` objects.

```
ggplot(Price.data[.indexmon(Price.data) %in% c(2, 3, 5)]['2010/2014'],
  aes(x=Dry_Gas_Y, y=Price_Gas_Y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm)
```